# How do I create a "love potion"?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, genetic-engineering

Lets say in 2069 a big interstellar corporation needs to create a "love potion" to subdue a religious pacifist rebel group that refuses to reproduce until they get independence.

This love potion doesn't need to be an actual potion, it can be anything that unconsciously suggests them to reproduce, although I would like it if it could be an airborne chemical. How can this be accomplished?

**Note:** The rebellion cannot be ended by force. It's a new colony and it will be a bad political move.

Comment: Why would the rebel group refusing to reproduce even be a problem?  First, human reproduction is on a time scale longer than most rebellions.  Second, if they don't reproduce, they eventually die out, solving the problem.  See e.g. the Shaker cult.

Comment: Is it some kind of really-have-to-make-them-cooperate-right-now-there-is-no-other-option scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple vectors for this without ever doing anything with regards to a "Love Potion" such as stop making their life comfortable, increase the death rate, make them poor, reduce their education, make the environment hotter. All of these things will cause people to reproduce more.

As far as an actual love potion. Basically, you just need to find the chemical concoction that is produced when people are horny... those would be interesting experiments to be a part of... and then just create a pill or gas of the concentrated concoction, or one that triggers the release of that in the body naturally.

You could also create a nanite swarm that hijacks the body of a person to make them horny/reproduce. There is no reason that this isn't possible. We're just technologically not quite there yet.

As far as "safe sex". No such thing really. You have enough sex and you'll win the lottery or if your always horny or whatever you'll forget at some point and this would happen more and more as the situation is prolonged because people would rather screw unsafely than go out to a store and kill the mood especially if you get them horny enough...

Of course the issue with anything like this is that it is a form of rape and any political body that authorizes it will be lynched. If I were in this predicament I'd go with a physical military assault than rape by proxy of an entire colony.

Answer (score 1):

This mainly addresses the problems that you'll need to surmount in order to achieve this effect.

- Your main problem is that men and women respond differently to
  [chemicals and hormones](http://www.everydayhealth.com/low-testosterone-pictures/dueling-testosterone-hormones-that-works-differently-in-men-and-women.aspx#02), therefore, whatever you do will likely hit
  one gender, but not the other. **Solution: separate living or working quarters mean that each gender is dosed with what that gender will need to make them want sex.**
- Then there's separating the desire for sex from the desire to have children. Those are two different things, and that's why we have birth control in the first place. While you might be able to introduce something which causes them to have a lot of sex, that doesn't mean they won't try to prevent pregnancy. **Solution: subliminal and non-subliminal advertising. TV shows with adorable babies and fulfilled parents. Ads that show the same, in as many forms of media as you can get. Other solution: Send families who already have babies to the planet. Nothing like a real, live baby to make a lady want one--although this is not always the case.**
- The next problem is: birth control. Birth control has a pretty wide
  spread. There's condoms, which when used properly considerably reduce
  pregnancy rates. As does pulling out, which while not highly
  effective, also will drive down the percentage. Of course, there's
  the pill, which fools a woman's body into believing she is newly
  pregnant. And the rhythm method. **Solution: find a way to boost fertility for both genders. This may be separate from getting them to have sex. They would have to be well-fed, get the appropriate amount of exercise, and the vitamins needed for fertility.**

There really isn't just ONE thing or one solution you can pump through the air. Rather, it must be a multi-pronged approach. Currently there is no one thing that MAKES people want babies.